# Setting a different taskbar icon to the icon displayed in the titlebar (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I have both dark and light versions of my application icon; the dark version works best on gray surfaces such as Windows XP taskbar, where the light version works best as an icon in the titlebar.

Is there a way I can set the icon in the taskbar to a different icon than the one used in my form in C# (P/Invoke is fine)?

Comment: Are they both separate projects or is it one project and do you want to set it programatically?

Comment: It's the same project (same form) and I want to set it programatically.

Comment: I read something in .Net 4.0 about the "Window.TaskbarItemInfo". It might be possible to do that via the overlay property.

Comment: I would get a better icon that looks good on both light and dark. Simply because you can't guarantee the colour preference of your users. How do you know the user is using stock xp theme?

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 15):

Send the WM_SETICON message to your form with different icon handles for the ICON_SMALL and the ICON_BIG parameter:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const uint WM_SETICON = 0x80u;
private const int ICON_SMALL = 0;
private const int ICON_BIG = 1;

public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, Properties.Resources.IconSmall.Handle);
    SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, Properties.Resources.IconBig.Handle);
}
```

Comment: great answer! +1 for sure!

Comment: Could you give me some more information? I don´t know how to apply this solution

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question but I came across it when trying to achieve the same thing, and well yes you can do this, on Windows 7/8 at least.

It turns out an ICO file doesn't just contain one image, it contains 9 different images at 9 different resolutions:

- 16x16
- 24x24
- 32x32
- 48x48
- 64x64
- 72x72
- 80x80
- 96x96
- 128x128

On Windows 7 and 8, the 64x64 image is used on the taskbar, and the 16x16 image is used on the icon which is placed on the top left hand corner of your form.

You can use a tool like [Greenfish Icon Editor Pro](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/gficoneditor.html) (I don't work for them or anything, this isn't a plug!) to have these as two seperate images, and then add this `*.ico` file as normal to your Windows Form/WPF form in Visual Studio.

The end result is shown below:

[image: WPF]

As you can see my WPF application has two seperate icons, one in the taskbar and another on the form.

Comment: Well, there could be any number of icons in an .ico file. Also, this solution might work but isn't really practically. Additionally: Windows doesn't necessarily use the 64x64 icon to display the taskbar icon. On a typical system with the default dpi setting a 32x32 icon would work. For higher dpi scales Windows will use different icon sizes for the title bar and the taskbar.

Comment: also, if you modified your icon before setting it to your form's icon (such as sizing a 32x32 icon to 16x16 with better quality than the default sizer does), then you may actually lose all the other sizes contained in your original icon file. @AndreasAdler answer is definitely the best one for the question that was asked.

Comment: Also, if you check the setting "Taskbar -> Use small taskbar buttons" windows will use the 16x16 icon as well.