# Hide icon in title bar but not in task bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an icon that I want to display in the taskbar; however, I don't want this icon to display in the title bar.  I tried setting `ShowIcon` to false, but that hides my icon in both the title bar and the task bar.  Is there any way to only hide it in the title bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the link Riz sent me in a comment to his answer, this was the solution I used:

```
using(Bitmap emptyImage = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    Native.SendMessage(this.Handle, Native.WM_SETICON, Native.ICON_SMALL, emptyImage.GetHicon());
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the FormBorderStyle property to either of following (depending on your scenario)

```
FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow
```

And keep ShowIcon to true.

This will hide the icon from the title bar and keep it in task bar.

Comment: Hi Riz, the FixedDialog solution didn't work.  The other two are alright, but on some older versions of Windows, this will also make the title bar and the "X" smaller.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder, I believe the FixedDialog is supposed to look smaller, so that one knows it's not resizable and isn't a "normal" window.

Comment: Which I understand, I just need a solution that doesn't alter the window in any way at all other than not showing that icon.

Comment: Then you could use one of the other properties suggested. :)

Comment: As I stated in my initial comment, that makes the "X" smaller on windows 8, and the title bar smaller on older versions of Windows.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048910/setting-a-different-taskbar-icon-to-the-icon-displayed-in-the-titlebar-c See if you set the ShowIcon to false and change the default icon displayed in taskbar.